# Is it possible to get information where a variable, handle, buffer are defined?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I write some little log files where i can see from which program something is called with the help of

`PROGRAM-NAME(i)`.
It would be really interesting if I could also get information about my variables, handles, buffers, ... and where they are defined.

`SOURCE-PROCEDURE:GET-SIGNATURE`

is a little step in the right way, but this gives me only the possible input and output of my source-procedure.

Answer (score 2):

Handle based objects have an INSTANTIATING-PROCEDURE property of type handle, that references the handle of the procedure that created the instance.

Alternative, if the Dynobjects.* log-manager entry type to get that information when an handle based object is created and deleted in the current client log file.

Comment: Thx for this hint.
In combination with recursive use of `INSTANTIATING-PROCEDURE` with
`FILE-NAME`
`INTERNAL-ENTRIES`
`GET-SIGNATURE`
i get a ton of new information for my log.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a lot of run-time data check out the "LOG-MANAGER" handle in general, particularly the 4GLTrace setting.